# How do I get values in XML string value of Node Items in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I have a STUPID Input XML file:

```
<Root>
  <Items>
  <![CDATA[
    <Item>
        <Name>Jonh Smith</Name>
        <Age>15</Age>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Name>Jim Catter</Name>
        <Age>14</Age>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Name>Michel Sharp</Name>
        <Age>16</Age>
    </Item>
   ]]>        
  </Items>
</Root>
```

So, `Items` element is a node. It is a leaf node with value is a "string" `<![CDATA[...]]>`.

And I have a XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">    
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
      <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Age</td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Root/Items/Item">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select='Name'/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select='Age'/></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And...my out put HTML (after transform XML and XSLT) file is:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Age</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

As you see! I can't show Name and Age. What do I need to write my XSLT to show HTML result like this:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Age</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Jonh Smith</td>
            <td>15</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Jim Catter</td>
            <td>14</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Michel Sharp</td>
            <td>16</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Can you help me?

Thank a lot!

Comment: I think you misunderstand the nature of your problem: CDATA is not markup. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60012720/changing-xml-format-based-off-cdata-using-a-xsl-template/60016451#60016451

Comment: If you switch to an XSLT 3 processor you can simply use `<xsl:for-each select="/Root/Items/parse-xml-fragment(.)/Item">` instead of `<xsl:for-each select="/Root/Items/Item">`.

Comment: Thank you! @MartinHonnen, but I can't switch to XSLT3.

Comment: For XSLT 1 or 2 processors not supporting the XPath 3.1 function `parse-xml-fragment` there might be a processor specific way to implement the extension by calling into the underlying platform (e.g. Java, .NET, PHP) but to tell we need to know which XSLT 1.0 processor exactly you use.